# Laravel Nova how to overwrite the nova LoginController

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

My project requires a username rather than email.  I had this working in Laravel 5.8 and Nova v2.1.0. After upgrading to L 6.x N  2.6.1 everything broke.  So I started over with clean L 6.x and N 2.6.1 install.
Now I want to customize the login but I do not want to edit any Nova Package scripts as before.
I've added this code to nova/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php and all works as expected.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

When I add the code to App/Nova/Http/Controller/LoginController.php (a copy of the original) the login still requires an email address. Or is using the original file in nova.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i do on my end

i override the App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php from

```
class LoginController extends Controller
```

to

```
class LoginController extends \Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\LoginController
```

if you want to use username or email on the login page you have to add this.
this method will determine how the user input they credential

```
public function username()
    {
        $login = \request()->input("email");

        $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
        \request()->merge([$field => $login]);

        return $field;
    }
```

because the user can login using email or username but the default login from nova only have 1 input box. have to add this to display if the user input wrong username or that username did not exist

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }
```

on my controller i have add other method to determine if the user is admin or able to access the backend or if the user is still active.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
            return redirect(config('nova.path'));
        }

        if($user->can('backend')) {
            return redirect(config('nova.path'));
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

by adding method to check user is active i need to add this method to check if the user can login

```
    private function activeUser($username)
    {
        $user = User::where($this->username(), $username)->first();
        if($user) {
            return $user->active;
        }
        return false;
    }

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $active = $this->activeUser($request->only($this->username()));
        if(! $active) {
            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }

        return parent::login($request);
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try.